# python+flask+mysql methods not allowed

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I've a question about an error using in python + flask

I'm trying to add and delete classes using mysql databases. 
It keeps saying"Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL."

This is the code i'm working with:

```
    #delete klas
@app.route('/delete_klas/<string:id>')
@is_logged_in
def delete_klas(id):
    if 'count' in session.keys():
        session['count'] += 1
    else:
        session['count'] = 1

    #create cursor
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    #execute 
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM klassen WHERE id = %s", [id])

    #commit
    mysql.connection.commit()

    #close
    cur.close

    flash('klas verwijdert', 'success')

    return redirect(url_for('intranet'))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: specify http methods in route `@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`

Answer (score 0):

The error says that that page you are calling with the

```
@app.route('/delete_klas/<string:id>') which requests a method.
```

You need add a post method to the route when you send a form through like this:

```
@app.route('/delete_klas/<string:id>' methods='POST')
```